# Viewing an RTSP stream

Tags: video-streaming

I have a number of Foscam Fi2918w cameras that all stream fine using HTTP.  I need to change one of them to use RTSP via VLC.  I consistently get back an error that says only that it can't open the stream (for example) `cvlc 'rtsp://IPADDRESS:88'` just produces:

```
00007f2c88001130] live555 demux error: Failed to connect with rtsp://192.168.254.18:88/
[00007f2c88004990] main stream error: connection failed: Connection refused
[00007f2c88004990] satip stream error: Failed to connect to RTSP server 192.168.254.18:88
[00007f2c88004990] main stream error: connection failed: Connection refused
[00007f2c88004990] access_realrtsp stream error: cannot connect to 192.168.254.18:88
[00007f2c88004990] main stream error: Connection failed
[00007f2c88004990] main stream error: VLC could not connect to "192.168.254.18:88".
[00007f2c94000c80] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[00007f2c94000c80] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://192.168.254.18:88/'. Check the log for details.
```

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Port 88 is Foscam's http port, so that's not a very good start, I believe.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Well, RTSP and HTTP requests are header-compatible enough that it's not unheard of for them to share a port. The server can parse all the headers identically and differentiate the two from the protocol version (e.g. "HTTP/1.1" vs "RTSP/1.0") on the request line. I dunno anything about the history of RTSP but my assumption is it was designed that way intentionally for convenience.

Comment: You're right.  I just ran a GetStreamUri and got "rtsp://onvif:XXXXX@192.168.1.50:88/videoMain".  But when I try this with mencoder, the FI9828W says "401 Unauthorized"..

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Yeah the error responses are similar enough that they can share logic on the server side, too (same deal e.g. "RTSP/1.0 401 Unauthorized" and I think they both use the same codes). But the reason for the "unauthorized" response is beyond me, since I don't have a Foscam device here to test with. Maybe a camera setting or mencoder option for that one. You got further than the OP though -- at least you got a connection going. ‍♂️

Comment: I wonder if the onvif user is the one needed for rtsp, since I'm sure I have the correct credentials: I used onvif to get the stream uri.

Comment: @bobc has left the buiding.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.foscam.com/faqs/view.html?id=81, the URLs are:

- rtsp://user:password@ipaddress:88/videoMain
- rtsp://user:password@ipaddress:88/videoSub
- rtsp://user:password@ipaddress:88/audio

So try adding videoMain or videoSub to your RTSP URL; and also make sure you're specifying a username and password if necessary.

Your "connection refused" error usually means it couldn't connect to the port, rather than a URL path error (which would happen after a successful connection), but the above is worth a shot since it's easy to try.

After that the next thing I'd do is go through the settings on the camera and make sure there isn't something you have to toggle to enable RTSP, and make sure that if the port number is configurable, it matches what you're trying to connect to. Also I believe the default port for RTSP is 554 so you could just cross your fingers and quickly try that on the client side before digging into camera settings.

Failing that, there's the other basic troubleshooting stuff (in no particular order):

- Does your PC have a software firewall blocking the outgoing connection? (If so try temporarily disabling it to test.)
- Is that the correct IP?
- Is it reachable from your PC by other means (e.g. can you access its configuration UI in your browser or through whatever the normal procedure is)?
- Can you ping it?
- Are your PC network settings correct? It's connected? It's on the same subnet as the camera (e.g. 192.168.254.x with mask 255.255.255.0 or whatever mask you're using)?
- Are the cables connected (link light on both ends?)
- Is port 88 open? (You could try hitting the camera with a port scanner tool)
- Is it accessible from a different machine (if you have something on your network to test with; even a smartphone or a tablet or something)?
- Is there another firewall between your PC and camera that could be blocking it?

I know that's not a definitive answer but with the information given that's all I can think of. Hope it helps or at least gets you going down the right path!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to watch the following two streams with VLC

```
rtsp://admin:karrewiet@192.168.1.50:88/videoMain
rtsp://admin:karrewiet@192.168.1.50:88/videoSub
```

I had to use the admin user, two other administrator accounts did not work, although using the correct credentials.  FI9828W kept asking for them.  Nor did mplayer work, no connection problem but just hanging.

Comment: I can confirm that 88 really is the port for Foscam (not the standard port for RTSP) and that similar settings work for me.
I even have it working from the Internet using "duckdns" to keep my public IP address mapped. I did have to port forward 88 in my router.